# How i use \nolinebreak

Tags: line-breaking

How do I use `\nolinebreak`. [image] I want no line breaks in my book. I want to use `\nolinebreak`.

Please help me

Comment: These are hyphenations. Use \raggedright if you don't want them.

Comment: Thank you. It's done. But it's no justified. How i use with justify and \raggedright

Comment: Check the hyphenat package. But justification and no hyphenation will either give overfull lines or (if you use \sloppy) quite bad spacing.

Comment: You wrote, "I want no line breaks." Actually, you very much do want line breaks. What you apparently do *not* want is word breaks, e.g., hyphenation of words. As @UlrikeFischer has already suggested, you may want to look into using the `hyphenat` package. Just prepare yourself for ugly-looking paragraphs with inter-word whitespace varying wildly across lines within a paragraph.

Comment: thank you guys. Almost done.